# HIERARCHICAL VIEW For Product Category odoo V8

Tags: view, odoo-8, hierarchical

I'm trying to create my own custom module for the products category with a hierarchical view.

My main requirement that i'll be able to create a view with folds , unfold capability.

Here's an example:

|Category Root (UNFolded)

```
 |Category A  (UNFolded)

         |Sub Category A1

 |Category B (UnFolded)

         |Sub Category B1

         |Sub Category B2

         |Sub Category B3

 |Category C (Folded)
```

---

If i click on category C Row I ll be Able to unfold it and see it's sub category.

I tried the following:
For The Class

```
 class odepoCategory(models.Model):
        _name = 'odepo.category'
        name = fields.Char(string='Nom Category')
        parentCategory = fields.Many2one('odepo.category', string='Categorie Pére', select=True, ondelete='cascade')
        subCategories = fields.One2many('odepo.category', 'name', string='Sous Categories')
```

For The View

```
<?xml   version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
  <data>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="enquiry_tree_view_leads">
    <field name="name">view.enquiry.leads.tree</field>
    <field name="model">odepo.category</field>
    <field name="field_parent">subCategories</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree toolbar="True" string="Enquiry Leads">
        </tree>
    </field>
</record> 

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="enquiry_tree_view_leads">
    <field name="name">view.enquiry.leads.form</field>
    <field name="model">odepo.category</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <form string="Shipping Information">            
        <group>
            <field name="parentCategory"/>
            <field name="name"/>
   <!--         <field name="subCategories"/> -->
        </group>
        </form>

    </field>
</record> 

 <record id="product_category_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Products by Category</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">odepo.category</field>
        <field name="domain">[('parentCategory','=',False)]</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p>
            Here is a list of all your products classified by category. You
            can click a category to get the list of all products linked to
            this category or to a child of this category.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>

                <!--    Action  to  open    To-do   Task    list    -->
                <act_window id="action_todo_task"
                        name="To-do Task"
                        res_model="odepo.category"
                        view_mode="tree,form"   />
                <!--    Menu    item    to  open    To-do   Task    list    -->
                <menuitem   id="menu    _todo_task"
                        name="To-Do Tasks"
                        parent="mail.mail_feeds"
                        sequence="20"
                        action="action_todo_task"   />
        </data>
</openerp>
```

Howerver i don't have a clue on how to show the hierarchical view.

Comment: you are lookinf for back end or website

Comment: Nope.Actually I'm creating my custom product category without inheritance. The Model is working. Only the view is not working. All the category are showed as the usual VIew, not as an hierarchical view. I understand that the domain filter is the solution but it's not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case You must have to define the **parent** and **child** **relationship** within that object.
Just Need to follow the product.category object from the Product Base Module in base addons Of Odoo

Just check below code and add the parent_id and child_id relation.

**parent_id make it as many2one relation type field**

**child_id make it as one2many relation type field**

```
_name = "product.category"
_description = "Product Category"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Name', required=True, translate=True, select=True),
    'complete_name': fields.function(_name_get_fnc, type="char", string='Name'),
    'parent_id': fields.many2one('product.category','Parent Category', select=True, ondelete='cascade'),
    'child_id': fields.one2many('product.category', 'parent_id', string='Child Categories'),
    'sequence': fields.integer('Sequence', select=True, help="Gives the sequence order when displaying a list of product categories."),
    'type': fields.selection([('view','View'), ('normal','Normal')], 'Category Type', help="A category of the view type is a virtual category that can be used as the parent of another category to create a hierarchical structure."),
    'parent_left': fields.integer('Left Parent', select=1),
    'parent_right': fields.integer('Right Parent', select=1),
}
```

Add the Code for the product Category view XML File :

```
    <record id="product_category_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.category.tree</field>
        <field name="model">product.category</field>
        <field name="field_parent">child_id</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree toolbar="True" string="Product Categories">
                <field name="name"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="product_category_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Products by Category</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.category</field>
        <field name="domain">[('parent_id','=',False)]</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_category_tree_view"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p>
            Here is a list of all your products classified by category. You
            can click a category to get the list of all products linked to
            this category or to a child of this category.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

In Your XML File You must have to set the field_parent as child_id and toolbar="True" in Tree View.
In your Product Category Action View just add the domain [('parent_id','=',False)]

If you do and configure well then the Odoo Automatically set the parent and child type List View for you.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Hey DaSaDiYa ChaiTAnYa Thank you for your quick answer. I used your view combined with my model however i can't get the desired hierarchical view. Do i need to inherit the product category view ? because i delete the inherit view line.

Comment: Base module have already there no need to inherit it if you can do customize one then create a separate object and do that things as I mentioned

Comment: I already modified my code on top as you advised me but as i said.But unfortunately it's not working the tree is not displayed in hierarchical view

Comment: okey but do it same I mentioned and check proper viewtype default as form type must be needed in action..